# Retrieve specific information from a form - Symfony2

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I want to know it is how to obtain specific data from a form sent by the user. That is, when the user submits the form, for example I want to save some data in a table, and the other in another table. Thanks for your help, sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: do you know how to create a form in Symfony?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all data (what I think you don't need, but for comprehension):

```
 $data = $form->getData();
```

For specific fields, e.g. Username (what you need):

```
 $username = $form["username"]->getData();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of answers to that question. Normally people using [Symfony Forms](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html) and [Doctrine](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html) to bind HTTP form requests to business objects. The forms documentation gives you a pretty good overview of standard practice.

But you can also do it manually using your own HTML forms, Symfony's [Request](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/http_fundamentals.html#requests-and-responses-in-symfony) class and some other database library.

```
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$comment = $request->request->get('comment');

/* INSERT INTO comments (comment) VALUES (:comment); Params [ :comment => $comment ]*/
```